# Cannot import gtk in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, gtk

I'm using pycharm. I got one project and I have a problem to run it. 
I got errmsg :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygtk'
```

In Pycharm I'm using python3 but I tried also on python2.
Without Pycharm in windows, I have the same problem.

Have someone solution to run scripts with gtk on Python3? It's even possible? I read that the gtk is no more supported, but I can't change a project.
Also, I tried to install pyGObject, but it's a problem with:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cairo'
```

The other posts found on SO doesn't work for me.

First lines in the code:

```
import pygtk, gtk
import numpy as np
import csv
```

....

Comment: Can you go in the Python interpreter page in the `Settings` of Pycharm and confirm that you see these two packages in the list of packages?
Also have you checked this: https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and how have you installed these packages? It would help to know.

Comment: pygtk is for GTK+ 2 and python 2. For GTK+ 3 use pygobject, following the link Eskapp gave you, and follow the [Python for GTK+ 3 tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).